# unexpected token while running the shell script

Tags: java, macos, shell

Here is the shell script snippet.

```
# OSX hack to CLASSPATH
JIKESPATH=
if [ `uname -s` = "Darwin" ]; then
  OSXHACK="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib"
  if [ -d "$OSXHACK" ]; then
    for i in "$OSXHACK"/*.jar; 
    do
      JIKESPATH="$JIKESPATH":"$i"
    done
  fi
fi
```

Not sure what exactly is the problem in this code I get this error while running the script

```
'Users/administrator/Desktop/dce/external/tomcat/bin/setclasspath.sh: line 87: syntax error near unexpected token `
'Users/administrator/Desktop/dce/external/tomcat/bin/setclasspath.sh: line 87: `    for i in "$OSXHACK"/*.jar;
```

I would like to know what exactly is causing this problem.

~~ other error with using @DuncG answer.

```
'Users/administrator/Desktop/dce/external/tomcat/bin/setclasspath.sh: line 88: syntax error near unexpected token `do
'Users/administrator/Desktop/dce/external/tomcat/bin/setclasspath.sh: line 88: `    do
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure but it looks like your `*` is not resolve. Changing to subcommand will ensure wildcard is expanded:

```
if [ -d "$OSXHACK" ]; then
    for i in `ls $OSXHACK/*.jar`
    do
      JIKESPATH="$JIKESPATH":"$i"
    done
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this seems to avoid the older problem but I get a new error now ~ updated in the question

Comment: Thanks but I got this fixed by again making sure I use `doc2unix` to convert the file to Unix format.

Comment: @DuncG : There is no point in creating a child process for running `ls` inside. In contrary, this would break the logic in the unlikely case that there are filenames with embedded white space.

Comment: Yes - `for i in "$OSXHACK"/*.jar` should have worked, maybe this issue was all because of the other `doc2unix` issue.